# List all tables in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

I want to list all table names from database. My application has to be independent from DBMS. Different DBMS has different command to list tables, e.g:

PstgreSQL:

`SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_table`s

MySQL:

```
show tables
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```

I think that I should use hibernate because writing different SQL query for all DBMS is uncomfortable.
There are examples in network how to list tables in hibernate, but all examples which I found list only mapped entitites. I want to list all table names regardless of hibernate entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2780375/4074715) explains how to do it using JDBC driver, which is IMHO a better approach then using hibernate for this. I'll post the code here also, for reference

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(3)); // 3rd column is table name
}
```

Comment: @lexicore My first thought was also dialects, but then jdbc came to my mind. Hopefully this works, as I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The way Hibernate makes HQL/JPQL queries and expressions cross-platform is by using [dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html). There's a dialect for each of the supported database.

To the best of my knowledge, listing tables is not a part of these dialects therefore what you want is most probably not possible OOTB.

But *you* can write your own dialects for your target databases. So you'd have a cross-database *QL in your application and database specifics would be cleanly abstracted into dialects.