# How to get all the table name from a specific database using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I wanted to retrive all the table name from a specific database. I tried the follwowing code

```
try {
        DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
        String[] types = {"TABLE"};
        ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it is giving nullpointer exception.

Comment: Precisely **WHERE** is it giving the nullpointer exception?

Comment: Precisely **WHICH** RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Uhm, I am not sure if I asked this before: 
 
Precisely WHERE is it giving the nullpointer exception?

Comment: on button click in swing I was creating the table in database. While in constructor I was trying to get the table name which was added in database. After executing I was getting null pointer exception , but after adding  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:testdata.db"); in constructor I am getting the output.

Comment: Okay, next time you will save yourself and everyone else from a lot of wasted time by explaining exactly where the problem is.  "WHERE" in this case means "on which line".  So, I suppose in your case the exception was being thrown by `connection.getMetaData()`.  Who would have thought of this.

Answer (score 1):

Following example shows that the method `conn.getMetaData()` would return the expected data.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:testdata.db");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST_TABLE"
                    + " (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,"
                    + " NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL, "
                    + " ADDRESS        CHAR(50))";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.printf("table name: %s%n", rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

produced output:

```
table name: TEST_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

(taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2780375/1843508)

Comment: I have tried the code , It doesn't give any output. I am calling the the following code in constructor and I am using Sqlite database .

Comment: Try running the following query (via JDBC) and see if it gives you results: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='table';