# JPA get table names from a certain mysql database

Tags: jpa

I am working on a project where i must  get all table names using JPA then store the names somewhere. Using mysql query I can use "Show tables" but using that in JPA doesn't work.How can i achieve this?

Comment: use raw jdbc `DatabaseMetaData`

Comment: JPA is not the technology for getting database info! It is object-based persistence

Comment: Please show an attempt to solve the solution with a specific question regarding a specific problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all table names from a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780284/how-to-get-all-table-names-from-a-database)

Answer (score -1):

I never tried something like that but you can try with that query:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='<your_database_name>';
```