# after getting all tables/Table names from jdbc java db how to make an array of their names

Tags: jdbc, java, javadb

after getting all tables/Table names from jdbc java db how to make an array of their names to use in Combobox in java?
I used DatabaseMetadata class but cant figure out how to get names to array etc, and what things to remember to use any class / interface from java api .

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all table names from a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780284/how-to-get-all-table-names-from-a-database)