# i want to fetch all tables in one database and display in jsp

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-data, database-metadata

like so

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Tables> getTableColumns(DataSource dataSource) throws MetaDataAccessException{
    List<Tables> table= (List<Tables>) JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(dataSource, new DatabaseMetaDataCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public Object processMetaData(java.sql.DatabaseMetaData dbmd)
                            throws SQLException, MetaDataAccessException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        List<String> ret = Lists.newArrayList();
                         ResultSet rs =dbmd.getTables(null, null,null,new String[] {"TABLE"});   

                         List<Tables> list =new ArrayList();
                         while (rs.next()) {
                             String table_name =rs.getString("table_name");
                            // ret.add(String.valueOf(rs.getObject(3)));
                             Tables table=new Tables();
                            table.setTable_name(table_name);
                            // ret.add(table_name);
                             System.out.println("hi user:" +table.getTable_name());
                         }
                        return ret;
                    }

        });
            return table;

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780284/how-to-get-all-table-names-from-a-database?rq=1

Comment: i need all tables to display in my jsp using spring mvc.pls help with